# Typescript type inference in ReturnType helper

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I can't understand why `Temp` type is `never` in the situation below. I understand why it is compatible with `(...args: any) => infer R` but how the type `never` was inferred from it?

```
// type ReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;


type Temp = ReturnType<never>;
```

Comment: Outside of a purely technical explanation, try looking at it intuitively. If you take something that can never happen (`never`), and ask what would happen if you called it (`ReturnType<>`), then surely that will never happen as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** [Distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and `never` is the empty union

**Long version:**

Lets first understand why `ReturnType<never>` being `never` is a bit surprising at first:

From the [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8652) introducing the `never` type:

> never is a subtype of and assignable to every type.

So this would mean if we ask the question does `never extend AnyOtherType`? The answer should always be yes.  So lets ask the compiler this question:

```
type R = never extends (...args: any) => any ? "Y" : "N"; // Evaluates to "Y"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASlC8UB2EBuEBOUIA9gSQBMBnKACgDoqBDDAc2IC4pqkQBKBAPhbagH4oAIgCaQqMyEA5IQG4gA)

So indeed the definition holds and `never` is a subtype of `(...args: any) => any`. But then why does `ReturnType<never>` resolve to `never`?  If inference fails, the default is usually `unknown` not `never` ([ref](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30637)). Lets try out this inference outside of `ReturnType`:

```
type T0 = never extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any; //unknown
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgDFAvFAdhAbhATlCAPYCFAEwGcoAKAOhoEMsBzUgLilpRAEokA+KASxQAzbFABKUAPziordiADcUAPTKArigDWAdwD2KKEA)

So this is where we have a really surprising result, `T0` is indeed `unknown`, while `ReturnType<never>` is `never` even thought all we did was inline the definition of `ReturnType` in `T0`.

The reason for this is [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). A type that has a condition over a naked type parameter, is distributive. This means that if `T` is a union, each union constituent will be run independently through the conditional type and all the independent results will be unioned to get the final result. So for example:

```
type T1 = ReturnType<(()=> number) | (() => string)> // number | string
```

How the compiler evaluates the type above:

```
ReturnType<(()=> number) | (() => string)>
  ->  ReturnType<()=> number> | ReturnType<() => string>
  ->  ((()=> number) extends (...args: any) => infer R) |  ((()=> string) extends (...args: any) => infer R)
  ->  number | string
```

Ok, so how does this relate to `never`. Well `never` is actually the empty union ([refernce](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22197#issuecomment-369261778)), a union with no constituents. This means that when running `never` through a distributive conditional type, the conditional type is actually never evaluated, since when trying to distribute, there is nothing to distribute over.

We can create a non-distributive version on `ReturnType` by not leaving `T` naked, and putting it in a tuple for example:

```
type ReturnTypeNonDistributive<T extends (...args: any) => any> = [T] extends [(...args: any) => infer R] ? R : any;
type Temp2 = ReturnTypeNonDistributive<never>; //unknown
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwFcBOA7AKuCA5A9igIgJYDOwShARgsIQG4QA8aUEAHsBCgCbFQAUAOiEBDJAHNiALijCUIAJRQAvAD4ZctUqgBtNAF0W7Tjx2CR4qeoXK1hFADMISWAYD8sKNNkgA3AChQSCg0CABbMAAmZVh4ZHRMXAISMkpqOkYUCHokFR8oAHp8hBQAaxQcAHcUPz8gA)

Comment: Good answer! 

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, yours was also good and along the same lines :)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a full explanation.